# Helm chart render string with special characters

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I want to render following line as string in helm chart. It contain special characters.

**text:  '{{ template "slack.template.text" . }}'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
**text: '{{"{{" }} template "slack.template.text" . {{"}}"}}'**

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `{{ quote }}` function to escape special characters in a string.

example:

```
text: '{{ quote (template "slack.template.text" . ) }}'
```

you can refer: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#quote-and-squote

Comment: I think the asker wants the literal string `{{ template ... }}` to appear in the outset, including the curly braces.  `quote` just wraps its argument in double quotes, it still would call the template when the chart is rendered.